# Parsing a file and making modification using regex

Tags: python, c, regex, scripting

I want have a piece of c code which has some defines. I want to parse the files do some change and create a new file. I want the offset value in the defines to be added to the corresponding base address indicated in the file. I want it to work if there are multiple base address and multiple offsets. I have shown below one of the input file and the the output I expected. How can I do this using regex or any other way.

**input.c**

```
/*******************************************************************
*
* Author: XYZ.
* Version: 1.0
*
*******************************************************************/

#define STDIN_BASEADDRESS 0x40600000
#define STDOUT_BASEADDRESS 0x40600000

/******************************************************************/

/* Definitions for driver UARTLITE */
#define XPAR_XUARTLITE_NUM_INSTANCES 1

/* Definitions for peripheral RS232_UART_1 */
#define XPAR_RS232_UART_1_BASEADDR 0x40600000
#define XPAR_RS232_UART_1_HIGHADDR 0x4060FFFF

/* Definitions for peripherals */
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_BASEADDR 0x76800000
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_HIGHADDR 0x7680FFFF
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_RESET_CNTRS_OFFSET 0x0
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_1_LOW_OFFSET 0xc
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_1_HIGH_OFFSET 0x10
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_3_LOW_OFFSET 0x1c
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_3_HIGH_OFFSET 0x20


#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_BASEADDR 0x74800000
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_HIGHADDR 0x7480FFFF
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_LPM_IP_OFFSET 0x0
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_LPM_IP_MASK_OFFSET 0x4
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_LPM_NEXT_HOP_IP_OFFSET 0x8
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_LPM_OQ_OFFSET 0xc


#define XPAR_MICROBLAZE_0_M15_AXIS_PROTOCOL GENERIC
#define XPAR_MICROBLAZE_0_S15_AXIS_PROTOCOL GENERIC

/******************************************************************/
```

**expected_output.c**

```
/*******************************************************************
*
* Author: XYZ.
* Version: 1.0
*
*******************************************************************/

#define STDIN_BASEADDRESS 0x40600000
#define STDOUT_BASEADDRESS 0x40600000

/******************************************************************/

/* Definitions for driver UARTLITE */
#define XPAR_XUARTLITE_NUM_INSTANCES 1

/* Definitions for peripheral RS232_UART_1 */
#define XPAR_RS232_UART_1_BASEADDR 0x40600000
#define XPAR_RS232_UART_1_HIGHADDR 0x4060FFFF

/* Definitions for peripherals */
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_BASEADDR 0x76800000
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_HIGHADDR 0x7680FFFF
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_RESET_CNTRS_OFFSET 0x76800000
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_1_LOW_OFFSET 0x7680000c
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_1_HIGH_OFFSET 0x76800010
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_3_LOW_OFFSET 0x7680001c
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_3_HIGH_OFFSET 0x76800020


#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_BASEADDR 0x74800000
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_HIGHADDR 0x7480FFFF
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_LPM_IP_OFFSET 0x74800000
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_LPM_IP_MASK_OFFSET 0x74800004
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_LPM_NEXT_HOP_IP_OFFSET 0x74800008
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR1_LPM_OQ_OFFSET 0x7480000c


#define XPAR_MICROBLAZE_0_M15_AXIS_PROTOCOL GENERIC
#define XPAR_MICROBLAZE_0_S15_AXIS_PROTOCOL GENERIC

/******************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C compilers are capable of doing math. No regular expressions or file modifications needed.

file.h:

```
/* Definitions for peripherals */
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_BASEADDR 0x76800000
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_HIGHADDR 0x7680FFFF
//Shorten name to make it easier for asker to read
#define BASEADDR XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_BASEADDR
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_RESET_CNTRS_OFFSET (BASEADDR + 0x0)
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_1_LOW_OFFSET   (BASEADDR + 0xc)
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_1_HIGH_OFFSET  (BASEADDR + 0x10)
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_3_LOW_OFFSET   (BASEADDR + 0x1c)
#define XPAR_NF10_ROUTER_OUTPUT_PORT_LOOKUP_0_BAR0_MAC_3_HIGH_OFFSET  (BASEADDR + 0x20)
#undef BASEADDR
```

And a pseudocode script (with real regexes) to do the transformation you want, if you don't like this solution:

```
#This script assumes that OFFSET #defines come after
# their associated BASEADDR #defines
input_file = open("path/to/input/file.c", read)
output_file = open("path/to/output/file.c", write)
baseaddr = 0
#In iteration of the loop, "line" will be a string
# containing a single line of the file
foreach line in input_file:
    #Get base address from the _BASEADDR #defines
    if regex_match("#define .*_BASEADDR (0x[0-9]{8})", line):
        baseaddr = hex_string_to_number(regex_groups[0])
        write_line(output_file, line)
    #Create new offset #define by adding offset from source
    # file to base address from source file
    else if regex_match("#define (.*)_OFFSET (0x[0-9]+)", line):
        new_val = hex_string_to_number(regex_groups[1]) + baseaddr
        #Format here is similar to C's sprintf.
        # Whichever language you choose will likely have
        # something that behaves differently
        new_line = format("#define %s_OFFSET %s",
                          regex_groups[0],
                          number_to_hex_string(new_val))
        write_line(output_file, new_line)
    #Pass through all other lines (blanks, HIGHADDRs, comments, etc)
    else:
        write_line(output_file, line)
```

Comment: The input.c is generated by a tool, i don't want to manually edit the file. So would prefer a script that can actually do it. Do you have any idea on how to do it using scripts.

Comment: Do you have control over the tool? If so, I'd modify the tool. I'll modify my answer to add a script with regular expressions to do what you want, and comment again once you're done with that.

Comment: Thanks for that. Script would be really great, i look forward to it. The tool doesn't allow me to modify that, the tool inherently prints the results like this. Moreover, input.c is just a small sample the actual file runs very long.

Comment: @user2532296 Okay, I just added in a pseudocode script. It's somewhat similar to Python, but isn't quite Python. Hopefully it gives you an idea of what the algorithm should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric I shall have a look and let you know . thanks ..

Comment: Hi Eric, from your pseudo code with some modification, I have written the pythonised code. I have added it for reference. Thanks a lot.